# Pushing directory to a bitbucket repository using python

Tags: python, git, github, git-push, bitbucket-api

I want to push entire parent directory on bitbucket using python.
I want to automate this using python:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin branch_name
```

I tried using bitbucket_api, but there is no command to push data.

Comment: You cannot push a directory.  Not even *Git* can do that.  What you *can* push are *commits*.  You need to make, and send, a commit.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are missing to config the remote repository(bit Bucket) URL before we are pushing to Origin. Please try with below commands.

git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL>
git push origin branch_name

Answer (score 1):

With python 3 you can use git:

> pip install GitPython

Clone a repository:

```
import git 

# Clone a remote repository 
repo_url = "https://bitbucket.org/project/repo"
local_path = "/path/to/the/repo"
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, local_path) 
print(f'Repository Cloned at location: {local_path}')
```

Add & commit:

```
repo = git.Repo('/path/to/the/repo') 

# Do some changes and commit 
file1 = 'test-sample.jpg'
file2 = 'input.txt'
repo.index.add([file1,file2]) 
print('Files Added Successfully') 
repo.index.commit('Initial commit on new branch') 
print('Commited successfully')
```

Push to the repo:

```
repo = git.Repo("/path/to/the/repo") 
origin = repo.remote(name='origin') 

existing_branch = repo.heads['main'] 
existing_branch.checkout() 

repo.index.commit('Initial commit on new branch') 
print('Commited successfully') 
origin.push() 
print('Pushed changes to origin')
```